# How to play audio from table

Tags: objective-c, audio

```
 playbutton = (UIButton *)sender;
audiostring = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
audiostring = [Audioarray objectAtIndex:playbutton.tag];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[audiostring valueForKey:@"url"]]] retain];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: &error];

[audioPlayer play];
NSLog(@"audio array : %@",audioPlayer);
```

For playing next audio from cell. Please tell me correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use accessory view of the cell and attach a play button there. This [Tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)
explains how to create a custom accessory view which is a button actually,so it has a selector.Following this tutorial you can easily know on which cell the button has been pressed.So, user can press the play button of specific cell.Then take the name of the file associated with that cell and apply the things you learn from [here](http://www.sagorin.org/2011/11/29/ios-playing-audio-in-background-audio/) to play your audio in background. Best of luck!

Comment: Please specify which portion or part is not working.I think in case of playing audio, this is the best place to get started : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/index.html